# Yii doesn't find PDO MySQL driver

Tags: mysql, pdo, yii

The yii requirements page says PDO extension + the mysql driver works, `phpinfo()` says that PDO and the MySQL driver is installed, I have configured the 'db' component in the main config file for my project generated with `yiic webapp`, checked and double checked that the settings are correct (and yes, I am using mysql).

I have made a new migration script in `/[mywebapp]/protected/migrations` and now I'm trying to run the `./protected/yiic migrate` command, but i just get an exception:

```
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver'
```

I have no idea what is wrong. I have been googling for 2 hours now and i find a lot of other users experiencing the same problems, but usually they are missing the drivers or something obvious. Is there anything i'm completely overlooking?

Comment: Command line PHP can be different from web-served PHP, are you sure you are using the correct `php` binary?

Comment: How can i know? The yiic script is bundled with yii

Comment: Add phpinfo() and see if PDO  mysql is listed there.

Comment: I solved it!!!

When using the shell to perform actions, the /config/console.php file needs to be configurated as well, which means entering the database credentials again.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the real answer being in the comments for this question, I am answering it here so that it appears as an answer.  Yiic.php migrate uses the configuration stored in console.php.  You need to set your database connection in there to use yiic.